# How to append to string in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I don't know how to add some string to itself in loop.

```
let parameters = [| [| ("name", "fdjks"); ("value", "dsf") |]; [| ("name", "&^%"); ("value", "helo") |] |] ;;
let boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";;
let body = "";;

for x = 0 to (Array.length(parameters) : int)-1 do
    let (_, paramName) = parameters.(x).(0) in
    let (_, paramValue) = parameters.(x).(1) in
    body = body ^ "--" ^ boundary ^ "\r\n" ^ "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"" ^ paramName ^ "\"\r\n\r\n" ^ paramValue ;
    print_endline(body)
done;;
```

but this gives error..
Any way to do this......?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(^)` operator concatenates two strings, e.g.,

```
# "hello" ^ ", " ^ "world!";;  
- : string = "hello, world!"
```

If you have a list of strings, then you can use the `String.concat` function, that takes a separator, and a list of strings and produces there concatentation in an effective way:

```
# String.concat ", " ["hello"; "world"];;
- : string = "hello, world"
```

Why is using the `(^)` operator in a cycle is a bad idea? Every concatentation creates a new string and then copies the contents of both strings into the new string. So appending `N` strings will end up in approximately `n^2` copying (where `n` is the length of a string). The same is true in Java and other languages/libraries where concatenation returns a new string, instead of mutating one of its arguments. A usual solution is to use the [StringBuilder pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), which in OCaml is represented with the [Buffer](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Buffer.html) module. So suppose, you don't have the `String.concat` function, and you would like to build your own efficient concatenation function (this could also be useful, since `Buffer` is a more general solution than `String.concat`, and will work when, for example, you input is not a list). Here is our implementation,

```
let concat xs =
  let buf = Buffer.create 16 in
  List.iter (Buffer.add_string buf) xs;
  Buffer.contents buf
```

This function will create a buffer that will automatically resize itself. The `16` is just an initial guess and could be any number. On the second line we just iterate over all strings and push the to the buffer, and finally, we ask the buffer to build the resulting string. Here is how we use this function:

```
# concat ["hello"; ", "; "world"];;
- : string = "hello, world"
```

Comment: While it is true that using `^` is less efficient than using the `Buffer` module, using the `Buffer` module is not necessarily better. Code using `^` tends to me more readable than a bunch of calls to `add_string`, and as long as this code is not a performance critical section, code readability is more important than performance.

Answer (score 1):

In OCaml variables are immutable by default. You need to use a reference if you want to change the value of a variable.

```
let parameters = [| [| ("name", "fdjks"); ("value", "dsf") |]; [| ("name", "&^%"); ("value", "helo") |] |] ;;
let boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";;
let body = ref "";;

for x = 0 to (Array.length(parameters) : int)-1 do
    let (_, paramName) = parameters.(x).(0) in
    let (_, paramValue) = parameters.(x).(1) in
    body := !body ^ "--" ^ boundary ^ "\r\n" ^ "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"" ^ paramName ^ "\"\r\n\r\n" ^ paramValue ;
    print_endline(!body)
done;;
```

See also [add elements to list in a loop in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537268/).

Please note that adding two strings in OCaml is an O(n) operation (n = number of characters), making it rather expensive for long strings. You can use the [Buffer module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Buffer.html) to concatenate strings efficiently. Using `^`, however, is much more readable.

A good compromise between readability and efficiency is probably, using the `Buffer` module for long and using `^` for short strings. Hence, using a Buffer for your outer iteration would be a good idea. The code looks as follows.

```
let parameters = [| [| ("name", "fdjks"); ("value", "dsf") |];
                    [| ("name", "&^%"); ("value", "helo") |] |] ;;
let boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";;
let body = Buffer.create 256;;

for x = 0 to (Array.length(parameters) : int)-1 do
  let (_, paramName) = parameters.(x).(0) in
  let (_, paramValue) = parameters.(x).(1) in
  Buffer.add_string body
                    ("--" ^ boundary ^ "\r\n"
                     ^ "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\""
                     ^ paramName ^ "\"\r\n\r\n" ^ paramValue);
  print_endline(Buffer.contents body)
done;;
```

Comment: I have to keep accessing body as **!body** after for loop right?

Comment: @VishalShingala Yes. You might bind !body to a new variable name, though. Even `let body = !body in' would work.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating recursively with an accumulator is the idiomatic way to do what you want in ocaml:

```
let parameters = [| [| ("name", "fdjks"); ("value", "dsf") |]; [| ("name", "&^%"); "value", "helo") |] |] ;;
let boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" ;;
let len = Array.length(parameters) ;;

let rec loop accum index =
  if index < len then
    let (_, paramName) = parameters.(index).(0) in
    let (_, paramValue) = parameters.(index).(1) in
    loop (accum ^ "--" ^ boundary ^ "\r\n"
          ^ "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\""
          ^ paramName ^ "\"\r\n\r\n" ^ paramValue)
         (index + 1)
  else print_endline accum
  in
  loop "" 0 ;;
```

Or better still look at the Array.fold_left function.

```
let parameters = [| [| ("name", "fdjks"); ("value", "dsf") |]; [| ("name", "&^%"); ("value", "helo") |] |] ;;
let boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";;

let () = print_endline
           (Array.fold_left
              (fun acc elt ->
                let (_, paramName) = elt.(0) in
                let (_, paramValue) = elt.(1) in
                acc ^ "--" ^ boundary ^ "\r\n"
                ^ "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\""
                ^ paramName ^ "\"\r\n\r\n" ^ paramValue)
              ""
              parameters)
```